# Add data to AWS SNS alarm payload

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I've setup some alarms monitoring specific lambda logs. If the word "error" is logged an alarm will be sent to my Slack channel. It works great, **however** the data on the SNS alarm is pretty limited.

I would really like to be able to get e.g. the "log stream" for the log which contained the word error, so I don't have to dig around to find the specific log in the AWS Console. (Then I could just created a link for it instead and provide it in Slack)

Does anyone know if this is possible? As far as I can see, there's no instruction on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest getting some inspiration from a [deep drive](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/get-notified-specific-lambda-function-error-patterns-using-cloudwatch/) by AWS on linking Lambda logging to Cloudwatch - you can create a Cloudwatch to SNS trigger from there